# Type to use in class to access variable

Tags: macos, cocoa, class, memory, automatic-ref-counting

I've a class myClass in which .h I have:

```
@property (strong) NSString *mystring;
```

I have a parent class in which I am accessing the "mystring" variable. However each time I do access it to compare it with another string, the memory consumed is increasing (using ARC).

```
           myClass *oneClass=<pointer to existing class>;

           for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
           {

                if ([oneClass.mystring isEqualToString:@"oneString"])
                {
                   // do nothing
                }
            }
```

-> Takes 10 MB memory more at each execution, and memory is not released.
Please don't look at the logic (the "oneString" is changing). How should I declare the *mystring* in the class (strong vs assign vs weak ?) so that no memory is consumed ?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know the memory use is not caused by `bla bla bla`? Use Instruments to see what is _really_ going on; do not guess.

Comment: The bla bla is actually a 'break'. I did some checks by replacing oneClass.mystring by @"another string", and the memory does NOT increase in such a case.

Comment: Cool, okay. So I have two suggestions: (1) declare `(copy, nonatomic)` instead of `(strong)`, just because it is better practice; and (2) wrap the `if` line (including its curly braces, of course) in an `autoreleasepool{}` and see if that helps any.

Comment: By the way, another odd thing is that you say `myClass *oneClass=<pointer to existing class>`. But a `myClass*` is not a pointer to a class but to an instance. No? I mean, you are not declaring a property on a class object, right? It's for instance variables. Objective-C has no class variables.

Comment: Why use "myClass *oneClass = <pointer to existing class>" that seems redundant. Why not use the pointer to the existing instance?

Comment: you are comparing to "oneString" 1000 times so create a string constant and use it.